# how to create an interactive graph in a simple way?

Tags: wordpress, graph, charts

Hi do you know a wordpress plugin or another tool that allows me to re-create in a simple way an interactive graph exactly like this: https://www.justpark.com/creative/sharing-economy-index/?

Thanks so much.

Comment: There is not much to the graph itself. You can implement functionality like that easily with tools like: Knockout.js, Vue.js, Angular, etc.

Comment: I think that is done with D3.js, I'm trying but isn't simple, because of I asked if there is a simpler way :)

Answer (score -1):

simple ? yea !

your answer is data browser

automatic chart creator based on any existing data on your sit just by 3 click

https://wordpress.org/plugins/data-browser/stats/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDNAC.jpg)